# How to set vscode error list to use the output of the nvcc

Tags: c++, cuda, visual-studio-code

I'm using visual studio code in ubuntu, because im using cuda I need to use nvcc and not gcc

The error list shown to me by vs-code is errors based on gcc compilation and not nvcc

[image: error list]

As you can see, I got two errors on the problems tab although the nvcc compile this code without any errors.

EDIT:
when I change the file end from cpp to cu. it dose not show me any errors. how do I do it to cpp?

Comment: nvcc won't compile that file correctly unless you rename it to main.cu

Comment: @talonmies it will. I'm compile it `nvcc -x cu main.cpp`  the `-x cu` tells nvcc to treat it as cu file. I don't have a compile problem. it is compiles and run. I jest don't want to the show me errors that are not there

Comment: So those errors you are showing are not "errors based on gcc compilation" at all. They are *intellisense* errors. You would need to turn it off for .cpp files or add an extension with cuda support, for example https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kriegalex.vscode-cudacpp

Comment: @talonmies You are right!, I jest turned it off with ` "C_Cpp.errorSquiggles": "Disabled",` in the settings.json. but the extension `vscode-cudacpp` works only on cu files and not cpp. how can I make vscode think that every cpp and h file is a cu file?

Comment: I have never used VS code so I can't help you with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding the extension `vscode-cudacpp`.
adding:

```
"problemMatcher": {
            "owner": "cpp",
            "fileLocation": ["relative", "${workspaceRoot}"],
            "pattern": {
                "regexp": "(.+)\\((\\d+)\\): (error|warning): (.+)",
                "file": 1,
                "line": 2,
                "severity": 3,
                "message": 4
            }
        }
```

to the `tasks.json` and turning off intellisense errors will give you an error list compatible with nvcc.

adding:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.cpp":"cuda" ,
    "*.h":"cuda"      
},
```

to the `settings.json` will color the cuda syntax also in the cpp and h files and not only in the cu and cuh files

Comment: thanks for this. But how do you turn off IntelliSense errors?